# Hide parent `<div>` if child do not have element `<ul>`

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="I">
    <h3></h3>
    <div class="C">
        <ul>...</ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using JQuery or JavaScript, how can I hide the whole `id="I"` element if the element `<ul>` does not exist?

Comment: Is it always the case that the UL will be nested within another div?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following Jquery to determine if a ul element exists inside of the div with id="I"

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var size = $("#I ul").length;

if (size === 0)
    $("#I").hide();
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z10sLrtf/1/)

EDIT:

I've updated my script since it wouldn't work if you have multiple div tags with an id of "I".  Based on your description, you would like to remove all div tags with id of "I" that do not contain a ul element.  Here is the updated JsFiddle that meets your question's requirement: [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/z10sLrtf/2/)

Here is the code to do just that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").each(function(index, element){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");

        var numOfUl = $(this).find("ul").length;

        if (id == "I" && numOfUl === 0){
            $(this).hide();   
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This does not work either. Maybe it is because the #I block is itself loaded using a script? @j08691

Comment: " #I block is itself loaded using a script" then instead of doing this on doc ready, make sure you execute this code after the #I is loaded.

Comment: If you want you can remove the logic that specifically looks for an element with an id of "I".  That will remove all div's that do not have a ul element inside of them.  You will of course need to adjust the logic to suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("#I:not(:has(>ul))").hide();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/w13uyqLx/1/)**

Comment: This would only function for immediate children of children, no?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.fn.isNot = function(trueFalse) {
    var elem = $(this);
    var _isNot = elem.is("*");
    var _parent = $(elem.selector.split(" ").slice(0, 1)[0]);
    return  _isNot 
            ? trueFalse(_isNot, elem, _parent) 
            : trueFalse(_isNot, _parent)
};

$("#I ul").isNot(function(trueFalse, parent) {
    console.log(trueFalse, parent);
    if (!trueFalse) {
        parent.hide()
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/ns09astu/